# How do I make custom scales on a scatter plot in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the diamonds data set to do some analysis for a project. I need to figure out how to change the x and y scales. When I use this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=carat,y=price))+geom_point()+ylab("Diamond Price")+
xlab("Diamond Cut")
```

the x scale is 0-5 and the y scale is 1000-5000. How can I change the scale and intervals?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can simply work with `scale_x_manual`. Read about it [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/scale_continuous.html). To be honest, You show no research effort with your answer. A simple Google search with these terms would result in useful references.

Answer (score 1):

Use `xlim` or `ylim`:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=carat,y=price)) +
  geom_point() + ylab("Diamond Price") +  xlab("Diamond Cut") + 
  ylim(0, 5000) + xlim(0,2)
```

Comment: can you specify intervals with xlim and ylim?

Comment: What type of interval? `xlim` n `ylim` will accept only two arguments. But you can plot the data in steps.

Comment: in steps? the q was about limits and intervals which you can do with scale_x and scale_y whereas xlim and ylim create the intervals for you